# Create batch to archive files using main folder name for archive name

Tags: batch-file, command, winrar

I am trying to create batch file and couldn't find solution anywhere on the web.
I would like to archive (Winrar) folder&subfolders (eg.Folder `A` in `C:\Temp\A`). Folder `A` has a bunch of subfolders & files.

I am using this command :

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -esh -m5 -mt2 -r -s -t "ZZZZ.rar"
```

Problem is that I would like archive to be named same as the name of the main folder (in this case folder "A" - `A.rar`), and archive to be send to folder `C:\Temp` (up one level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have WinRAR, so I can't check the syntax for the rar command, but you could create a batchfile (backup.bat) like:

```
cd %1
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -esh -m5 -mt2 -r -s -t "..\%1.rar"
cd ..
```

And invoke it with

```
backup A
```

from the *temp* folder. That might be a start...

Comment: Batch file is in folder A 'cause I have bunch o folders that need to be archived in "Temp" folder. Using your command I get archive where it needs to be but archive name is ".rar" (archive doesn't have a name).

Comment: Maybe this is the problem : I get " the system cannot find the path specified" when I try cd %1 in CMD

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
(
CD\
C:
cd "Temp\A"
)
"%programfiles%\winrar\rar" a -r "C:\ZZZZ.rar"